# Regular expression for Invoice Number

Tags: regex

I am new to Stackoverflow and I need your help to match payment invoice number. So that user can't input wrong invoice number. It should match the invoice pattern like `612(fixed) 10/20/30/40/50(only one from 5 of them) 001-064(one at a time) 0000(fixed) 01-64(one at a time) 00(fixed) and then 0001-9999(allowed)`

If I show you one invoice number it'll be like this one `612 30 005 0000 55 00 1234` without any space like this `61230005000055001234`

I can't figure it out how could I do this. please help me if you can.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please provide some input->expected output examples.

Comment: Sorry to say but I can't Regex. I am a newbie in wordpress theme development. I am trying to understand Regular expression but I failed. But my client need it urgently. So what can I do?

Comment: I was trying (612+(10|20|30|40|50)+(001|002|003|004|005)+0000+(01|64|55)+00) but last 4 digit missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^612\s?[1-5]0\s?0(?:[0-5]\d|6[0-4])\s?0000\s?(?:[0-5]\d|6[0-4])\s?00\s?\d{4}$
```

Should do the job for you, assuming that spaces are optional, but in fixed position and only single ones.

- `^` is an anchor for the beginning of the string
- `612\s?` matches 612 literally, followed by an optional space
- `[1-5]0\s?` matches 1/2/3/4/5 followed by 0 and an optional space
- `0([0-5]\d|6[0-4])\s?` means 0 followed by either 0-5 and any digit or 6
  and 0-4, followed by an optional space
- `0000\s?` matches 0000 literally, followed by an optinal space
- `([0-5]\d|6[0-4])\s?` is either 0-5 and any digit or 6 and 0-4, followed by an optional space
- `00\s?` matches 00 literally, followed by an optional space
- `\d{4}` means any 4 digits
- `$` is an anchor for the end of the string

https://regex101.com/r/iU5jY5/3

Comment: No need to actually capture the subsequences - use `(?:` rather than `(`

Comment: For the explanation +1 as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
612[1-5]00(?:[0-5][0-9]|6[0-4])0000(?:0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4])00[0-9]{4}
```

See [a demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pW9bD0/2).