# Regex for alphanumeric with at least one digit

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm looking for a *regex* for **Invoice Number** in Vbscript
It can have alphanumeric but at least one numeric digit is a must.

I'm using the below regex but it matches *ALPHA* String `INVOICE` also. It need to have at least one digit

```
\b(?=.*\d)[A-Z0-9\-]{5,12}\b
```

Expected Match String

> 1233444
> M62899M
> M828828
> 783838PTE
> A751987

Expected Unmatch String

> INVOICE
> ubb62727
> XYZ
> 123

If we use `([A-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[A-Z0-9]*)`, I can't specify the length.

Please suggest a proper regex. Please note its totally different from the suggested duplicate as the requirement, format is different.

Comment: Add a positive lookahead with a beginning-of-string anchor (`^` or `\A`): `^(?.*\d)`.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/w0kyNL/1)

Comment: @Lankymart The requirements in the proposed duplicate are quite different.

Comment: @tripleee The requirements might be, but the implementation (how you group digits exclude certain characters etc is exactly the same). I'm not saying it's a solution but it shows how they could structure the RegEx to get the output they require. The principles are exactly the same, both are trying to identify invoice numbers (The nature of an Invoice Number means they won't be exactly the same).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for Invoice Number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642039)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)

Comment: The language tag is appropriate here. It provides context for which regex engine the asker is using and it tell answerers what language the expected solution should be in. Please cease and desist from any further rollbacks. If you want to discuss this further, take it to [Meta].

Comment: https://regular-expressions.mobi/vbscript.html?wlr=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blanket `.*` in your lookahead will happily skip past the trailing `\b` if it has to. Make it more constrained, so it can't.

```
\b(?=[-A-Z]*\d)[A-Z0-9-]{5,12}\b
```

(I removed the backslash before the `-`; if you really want to allow a literal backslash, obviously add it back, to the character class in the lookahead also. A dash at beginning or end of a character class is unambiguous and doesn't require a backslash escape; this is also the only way to have a literal dash in a character class in many regex dialects.)